# Jquery - Images appearing at different times

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have some code I have used to make a simple tabbed Jquery menu. At the moment the whole `<ul>` is sliding in and I would like each `<li>` item in the selected `<ul>` to slide in with a slight pause between each one, instead of coming in as one.

**The jQuery code is:**

```
$(function() {
    var tabMenu = $('div#showcase-content > ul')
    tabMenu.hide().filter(':first').show();

    $('ul.tabbedMenu a').click(function() {
        tabMenu.hide();
        tabMenu.filter(this.hash).delay(300).show("drop");
    }).filter(':first').click();
});
```

**and my HTML is:**

```
<div id="showcase">
    <div id="showcase-content">
        <ul class="tabNavigation" id="intro">
            <li class="active"><a title="proj1" href="#zonkey"><img alt="" src="images/project-logos/freesound.png" /><br />Zonkey Media</a></li>
            <li><a title="proj2" href="#freeside"><img alt="" src="images/project-logos/freesound.png" /><br />Freeside Media</a></li>
            <li><a title="proj3" href="#windy"><img alt="" src="images/project-logos/freesound.png" /><br />Windy Arbour</a></li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="tabNavigation" id="design">
             <li><a title="proj4" href="#american"><img alt="" src="images/project-logos/freesound.png" /><br />American Football</a></li>
             <li><a title="proj5" href="#minus"><img alt="" src="images/project-logos/freesound.png" /><br />Minus the Bear</a></li>
             <li><a title="proj6" href="#manchester"><img alt="" src="images/project-logos/freesound.png" /><br />Manchester Orchestra</a></li>
             <li><a title="proj7" href="#brand"><img alt="" src="images/project-logos/freesound.png" /><br />Brand New</a></li>
             <li><a title="proj8" href="#glassjaw"><img alt="" src="images/project-logos/freesound.png" /><br />Glassjaw</a></li>
             <li><a title="proj9" href="#set"><img alt="" src="images/project-logos/freesound.png" /><br />Set your Goals</a></li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="tabNavigation" id="print">
             <li><a title="proj10" href="#crystal"><img alt="" src="images/project-logos/freesound.png" /><br />Crystal Fighters</a></li>
             <li><a title="proj11" href="#cursive"><img alt="" src="images/project-logos/freesound.png" /><br />Cursive</a></li>
             <li><a title="proj12" href="#bright"><img alt="" src="images/project-logos/freesound.png" /><br />Bright Eyes</a></li>
             <li><a title="proj13" href="#newfound"><img alt="" src="images/project-logos/freesound.png" /><br />New Found Glory</a></li>
             <li><a title="proj14" href="#lightspeed"><img alt="" src="images/project-logos/freesound.png" /><br />Lightspeed Champion</a></li>
             <li><a title="proj15" href="#fireworks"><img alt="" src="images/project-logos/freesound.png" /><br />Fireworks</a></li>
             <li><a title="proj16" href="#modest"><img alt="" src="images/project-logos/freesound.png" /><br />Modest Mouse</a></li>
             <li><a title="proj17" href="#nightmare"><img alt="" src="images/project-logos/freesound.png" /><br />Nightmare of you</a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
     <div id="showcase-menu">
         <ul class="tabbedMenu">    
             <li class="active"><a href="#intro">intro</a></li>
             <li><a href="#design">design</a></li>
             <li><a href="#print">print</a></li>
          </ul>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated! And ignore the content, as it's just for test purposes ...

Comment: Do you mean that you want the #showcase-content items to slide in one by one?  Do you want this to happen on page load or only on click of the .tabbedMenu items?

Answer (score 0):

take this code with a grain of salt.  but one solution would be to add a increasing delay on each li element you are showing:

```
var tabMenu = $('div#showcase-content > ul')
$('li', tabMenu).hide();

$('ul.tabbedMenu a').click(function() {
  var delay = 300;
  $(this.hash + ' li').each(function(i, e) {
    $(e).delay(delay).show("drop");
    delay += 600;
  });
}).filter(':first').click();
```

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cPpqf/2/) demoing this